# Are 1080p monitors better than a 4k monitor?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Ok so I own an asus 144 mhrz 1 ms response time monitor (for gaming) and i was able to stream a 4k video on it, keep in mind this is a 1080p monitor and it looked pretty good. So why do people even get 4k monitors if 1080p monitors can already display 4k?

**This me my theory so if you can please address it:** 4k monitors display 4k images and movies 100% of the time regardless if they're set up to stream Ultra HD, and while you can view 4k on a 1080p monitor you have to find special content on lets say youtube and other special videos designed to stream 4k content on a 1080p monitors?

Is this assumption correct?

Final question: Will 4k be greatly diminished if it's not an IPS panel? I recently bought this ASUS 4k monitor: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1053606&gclid=Cj0KEQiAyvqyBRChq_iG38PgvLgBEiQAJbasd726W5_OegsgietkLPh-Nqm-EDX5cHvQ22SMwwfFHNwaAomr8P8HAQ&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&A=details&Q= and I would like to know if I will get the same image quality as in an IPS panel? I don't really care about the viewing angles since I'm only going to be using it looking straight at the screen, but in terms of **image quality** lets say on movies, videos, and gaming would an IPS be superior? Pretty much what I'm asking is would 4k look better on a TN panel or an IPS panel or would it not make a difference?

Comment: I think some of your assumptions are bad.  A monitor can't display more resolution that the pixels it contains.  If you start with a higher resolution image, it will be down-sampled or interpolated to fit the screen.  A monitor can't display more detail than the source contains.  If you display lower-resolution source material, it's extrapolated or up-sampled to fill the screen.  The best and sharpest detail will come from displaying source material at its native resolution on a monitor that can display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is a bit misleading, "better" is subjective, and what is better for you might not be better for someone else.

Firstly, those videos are downsampled down to 1080p, you aren't really viewing 4k content at 4k, but here's the thing; you can upload an uncompressed 1080p video to YouTube upscaled to 4k, it won't actually be 4k, but the quality will be much better than other 1080p videos due to 4k videos having a much higher bitrate allowance than if you were to upload a 1080p video and then have YouTube compress it.

If you were to view a high-quality uncompressed 4k video on a 1080p monitor vs an actual 4k monitor, there would be a huge difference.

Basically, your 1080p monitor won't have more than 1920x1080 pixels when you're watching a 4k YouTube video.

And to answer your second question, the color depth and accuracy is generally much better on an IPS, but whether you'd call it a significant  difference depends on who you ask. Personally, I wouldn't notice it unless I compared the two right next to each other, but I would definitely know by the viewing angle.